# WP Snippet to hide and prevent users from changing account_display_name

Tags: php, wordpress, code-snippets

Evening everyone. I tried to look around the web to find a solution to this but couldn't really find anything related. I just need to write a snippet that prevent users to change their display name by hiding the field in the "my account" page or any other smarter way possible. Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From your question I can assume that you are using WooCommerce. You need to make a couple of things done to achieve it:

1. Remove **account_display_name** field from **My Account** template file:

Firstly, duplicate form-edit-account.php file

> /wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/templates/myaccount/form-edit-account.php

to your child theme folder

> /wp-content/themes/**your_child_theme**/woocommerce/myaccount/form-edit-account.php

Then open copied file and remove html markup and php code related to **account_display_name** field:

```
    <p class="woocommerce-form-row woocommerce-form-row--wide form-row form-row-wide">
    <label for="account_display_name"><?php esc_html_e( 'Display name', 'woocommerce' ); ?>&nbsp;<span class="required">*</span></label>
    <input type="text" class="woocommerce-Input woocommerce-Input--text input-text" name="account_display_name" id="account_display_name" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $user->display_name ); ?>" />
    <span><em><?php esc_html_e( 'This will be how your name will be displayed in the account section and in reviews', 'woocommerce' ); ?></em></span>
    </p>
    <div class="clear"></div>
```

2. Use **woocommerce_save_account_details_required_fields** hook to unset **account_display_name** field from the required fields. This is necessary to avoid validation error when saving changes on My Account page.

Place following php code into your child's theme functions.php file:

```
    add_filter('woocommerce_save_account_details_required_fields', 'remove_required_fields'); 
    function remove_required_fields( $required_fields ) {
        unset($required_fields['account_display_name']);
        return $required_fields;
    }
```

Comment: thank you for your reply Timofei. I made the changes, but I had to go straight to the woocommerce plugin files to edit the html and php markup related to the display_name row. Is there any way to keep it into the child theme aswell?

Comment: @mnrlab , of course you can make template changes through child theme. Please read carefully step 1, that I described in my answer. You need to copy **my-account.php** file to `/woocommerce/myaccount/` folder inside your child theme's folder. For more information please refer official [Woo template structure docs](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/template-structure/)

Comment: Oh I'm so sorry, I didn't realize that step included the plugin folder! It makes absolute sense now! thank you very much

Comment: Not sure this is still valid. Current `my-account.php` file only has 36 lines and none of them refer to display name.

Comment: Hello RichardU. Please have a look into /wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/templates/myaccount/form-edit-account.php file.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your question. You can insert this code into your theme functions.php or use [Code Snippets](https://wordpress.org/plugins/code-snippets/) plugin. Hopefully, it will work.

```
function wp_disable_display_name() {
    global $pagenow;
    if ( $pagenow == 'profile.php' ) {
    ?>
        <script>
            jQuery( document ).ready(function() {
                jQuery('#display_name').prop('disabled', 'disabled');
            });
        </script>
    <?php
    }
}
add_action( 'admin_head', 'wp_disable_display_name', 15 );
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply Monzur, even if your solution looks faster, I had a website firewall that is preventing me from activating this snippet, so I'll try the other solution first and, if not working, I'll go for your instead.

Comment: This is not good though, I could just disable JS and then edit it

Answer (score 0):

The best solution is to unset the variable in the backend and also disable the field in the frontend (like Monzur stated in his answer), so that users do not get confused. The following code (as a plugin) does the job for me:

```php
add_action('personal_options_update', 'disable_name_edit');
add_action('edit_user_profile_update', 'disable_name_edit');

function disable_name_edit($user_id) {
    if (!current_user_can('edit_user', $user_id)) {
        return false;
    }

    // Prevent users from changing their first and last names
    if(isset($_POST['first_name'])){
        unset($_POST['first_name']);
    }
    if(isset($_POST['last_name'])){
        unset($_POST['last_name']);
    }
    if (isset($_POST['display_name'])) {
        unset($_POST['display_name']);
    }
}

// From Manzurs answer
add_action('admin_head', 'wp_disable_display_name', 15);
function wp_disable_display_name() {
    global $pagenow;
    if ( $pagenow == 'profile.php' ) {
    ?>
        <script>
            jQuery( document ).ready(function() {
                jQuery('#display_name').prop('disabled', 'disabled');
                jQuery('#first_name').prop('disabled', 'disabled');
                jQuery('#last_name').prop('disabled', 'disabled');
            });
        </script>
    <?php
    }
}
```